# Including django templates in other templates so they are actually parsed

Tags: django, django-templates

Django's inheritance structure is driving me crazy.

I'm creating several skins, each with a two-column and three-column layout:

```
site1
  - two_cols.html
  - three_cols.html
site2
  - two_cols.html
  - three_cols.html
```

The three_cols.html layout extends two_cols.html and just adds an extra column to the layout with an extra django-cms placeholder for content.

For both site1 and site2 almost the only change at this stage is a different stylesheet name, so I want to move two_cols.html and three_cols.html into a 'common' directory, and just have the ones under site1 and site2 extend them.

So:

- two_cols.html sets a block name for the CSS path
- three_cols.html extends two_cols.html and provides an extra column

I've done this for the two col layout and it works fine. However, for the three_col layout in site1 for example, I want to extend site1/two_cols.html (which sets the CSS path) and then just include the contents of 'common/three_cols.html' (which defines the extra column).

This doesn't work for me because the three_cols.html contains django-cms placeholder tags which, because I'm only 'including' the template, apparently are not parsed, but just evaluated.

To say this another way, I want some settings in site1/two_cols.html to be able to be used from site1/three_cols.html where they both extends different templates.

### Summary

My issue is how can I include something so it's as if it was in the parent template (which the django docs say include won't do: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#include)?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do this with normal `extends`? `three_cols` can extend `two_cols` and add another column inside the main block, using `block.super` to render the original two columns.