# Breaking up large django templates: when {% include %} and {% ssi %} don't have enough context

Tags: django-templates

Django's [{% include %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include) and [{% ssi %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-ssi) can render or incorporate a template.  But they are designed to process the template and return the HTML.  As the docs say *"This means that there is no shared state between included templates – each include is a completely independent rendering process."*

But what if I want shared context?  What if I `{% include 'extra/map.html' %}` and need to add a block to the `<head>` section? How can I best break up a large template into parts, and keep the context?  The {% include %} mechanism seems potentially much clearer than extending the base, but the context issue gets in the way.

See also [Including django templates in other templates so they are actually parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340406/including-django-templates-in-other-templates-so-they-are-actually-parsed)